# Getting http 403 error while accessing photoURL of a firebase User

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, angularfire2

I am successfully authenticating an user with firebase authentication from an angular project which is hosted in google app engine. But when i am trying to display the photourl mapped with the user object, i am getting the http 403 error code.

Do i need additional permission in the app level to access the photourl?

Example photo url: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/s100x100/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=69aa0ab876bc8904fb59749a5e70382a&oe=598D6773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got solved in a strange way. From firebase console when i deleted the user and logged back in the photo url started working fine.

Comment: i am guessing the photoURL goes stale and we need to refresh it. Any thoughts on how to refresh it programmatically, without having the user logout and log in?

Comment: How can this be the solution in production

Answer (score 27):

add `referrerpolicy="no-referrer"` to the img tag, it worked for me

Comment: for me too! Thanks

Comment: Yeah this worked for me too, I'd love to know why that fixes it if anyone has an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the work around by adding no-referrer in referrerpolicy

[image: adding no-referrer in referrerpolicy]